# Return `f`'s result if `f` has a non-void return type - how to refactor this pattern?

Tags: c++, refactoring, metaprogramming, c++14, return-type

I have a `step(f)` function that:

1. Executes some code before calling `f`.
2. Calls `f()`.
3. Executes some code after calling `f`.
4. Returns `f`'s result value **if `f` does not return `void`**.

The small piece of code implementing `step`  bothers me more than it should, because of the fourth point described above:

```
template <typename TF>
auto step(TF&& f)
{   
    // Execute some actions before `f`. 
    do_something();

    using f_return_type = decltype(f());
    return static_if(std::is_same<f_return_type, void>{})
        .then([](auto&& xf) mutable
            {
                // Do not return anything if `xf` returns void.
                xf();

                // Execute some actions after `f`.
                do_something_after_f();
            })
        .else_([](auto&& xf) mutable
            {
                auto result = xf();

                // Execute some actions after `f`.
                do_something_after_f();

                return result;
            })(std::forward<TF>(f));
}
```

*(Note the repetition of the call to `f` and to `do_something_after_f`.)*

I have to use some kind of conditional compile-time *(either template specialization or `static_if`, as shown in the example)* to branch depending on `f`'s return type.

Ideally, I would like this to compile:

```
template <typename TF>
auto step(TF&& f)
{   
    // Execute some actions before `f`. 
    do_something();

    decltype(auto) eventual_result = f();

    // Execute some actions after `f`.
    do_something_after_f();

    return result;
}
```

But it doesn't, because `eventual_result` can be `void`, which is an incomplete type.

**Is there any way of refactoring this code in order to avoid the repetition in calling `f()` and `do_something_after_f()`?**

Comment: Are you looking for `optional`? I can't tell from the question why you need to return something if you just discard it.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper, The main problem is that we want the function to return whatever `f` returns, but because there's code after the call to `f`, its value must be stored. However, you can't store a value of `void`, meaning you need two versions: one for an `f` with a return type of `void` and one for other return types.

Comment: I could see something working if you abstract out having two versions into a sort of `void foo(...) {/*before*/ return callAndThen(f, [&] {/*after*/});`

Comment: @chris Yes, but `step` will return `void` if the function returns `void`.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper, Exactly, and it's the `decltype(auto) eventual_result = f();` that causes a problem. If `f` returns `void`, you're doing `void eventual_result = f();`, which is not legal. There was a proposal to make that legal, but it got rejected because changing the language to allow `void` as a value got complicated quickly.

Comment: @chris No I understand the problem, what I don't understand is what OP intends to do with the `eventual_result` once it's returned from `step`. Don't you basically have the same problem?

Comment: @sleeptightpupper: http://pastie.org/10855286

Comment: @sleeptightpupper, The point is that the caller passes `f` and knows what it returns. If the caller itself has `f` passed in for whatever reason, it can reuse the answer to this, and so on until someone knows what to do with the return value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have `do_something_after_f()` run after the return statement by putting it into the destructor of a local variable.

```
struct Cleanup {
    ~Cleanup() { do_something_after_f(); }
} cleanup;
return f(); // it's legal to return a void expression in C++
```

Comment: Devilishly clever!

Comment: I considered this, but thought that capturing `this` would result in even more code... on the other hand, I can abstract everything behind a `make_scope_guard(f)` function and it's going to be much nicer than the `static_if` solution. Probably going to accept this answer after I experiment with it, thanks!

Comment: @VittorioRomeo remember that the dtor is also called when `f` throws, but in the original code `do_something_after_f` would not be called. You can catch this with `std::uncaught_exception()`

Comment: @Brian Such a destructor has a non-throwing exception specification, thus it would terminate the program if `do_something_after_f` throws an exception. Am I right? Quite risky.

Answer (score 4):

I think @Brian's solution is it, since it's short and practical. Here I'm showing just an alternative

```
template<typename T>
struct taken {
   T &&take() {
      return std::forward<T>(t);
   }

   T &&t;
};

struct take_or_void {
   void take() { }
};

template<typename T>
inline taken<T> operator,(T &&t, take_or_void) {
    return taken<T>{ std::forward<T>(t) };
}
```

Now you can write it as

```
return ([](auto t) -> decltype(auto) {
   do_something_after_f();
   return t.take();
})((f(), take_or_void{}));
```

Comment: You deserve a +1 for the overloading of `operator,`.

Comment: Not sure. The `forward` within the `operator,` makes sense for you are dealing with a forwarding reference. Is the one used within `taken` useless instead? You are not actually capturing a forwarding reference there, `T &&` has a completely different sense, am I wrong? I mean, you know the actual type of `T` there and you are move constructing a copy of it in `operator,`. Wouldn't be enough to return `t` as is and move construct it back to the caller?

Comment: @skypjack if `f` returns a value, like `std::string`, `T&&` will be `std::string&&`, but `return t;` would return an lvalue because `t` is a named rvalue reference. That would not compile because the return type is `std::string&&`. The actual type of `T` may either be a non-reference type for rvalues, or an lvalue reference type for lvalues. I don't know it.

Comment: Right, actually I'd have used `T t;` and a clean `return t;`, using again `T` as return type for `take`. I'm sure I'm missing something doing like that, but I cannot figure out what if I look at the way you are using it. Also, thank you for your responses.

Comment: @skypjack i didn't want to move or copy the value, which may be costly, therefore I took it by reference. Actually, now that you say it, since I'm taking it by reference, I must not store the `taken` object. I need to convert it back to the lambda style I used earlier, where the take-by-reference was safe and incurred no cost. Thanks for making me notice :)

Comment: Thank you for giving me a response!! :-) I really like your solution and I want to fully understand it. So, now you get a reference to a temporary that outlives the whole expression. It makes sense. Anyway, there is still a _move_ when it does `return t.take();` (tried with a custom struct) and I'm trying to figure out to what it is due. Any idea?

Comment: @skypjack the move probably is due to the return type of the lambda which here is not a reference because it's auto deduced. If you use `return ([](auto t) -> decltype(auto) { ...`, this should be fixed.

Comment: I thought the same and tried it before to ask. It didn't solve. Well, I missed the fact that I was executing the lambda in a function that has `auto` return type for itself!! :-) ... Confirmed, `decltype(auto)` solves, my fault not to have got it a couple of hours ago while I was experimenting. Thank you very much for your responses. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might delegate the function call and assign a result to a structure able to represent 'void':

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// call

template <typename R>
struct Result
{
    R value;
    Result(R&& value) : value(value) {}
    R&& operator () () { return std::move(value); };
};

template <>
struct Result<void>
{
    void operator () () {};
};

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
inline
typename std::enable_if<! std::is_same<void, typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>::value,
    Result<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>>::type
call(F&& f, Args... args) {
    return Result<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
inline
typename std::enable_if<  std::is_same<void, typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>::value,
    Result<void>>::type
call(F&& f, Args... args) {
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); return Result<void>();
}


// test

template <typename TF, typename ...Args>
auto step(TF&& f, Args... args)
{
    // ...
    auto result = call(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // ...
    return result();
}

inline void f() {}
inline int g(int i) { return i; }

int main()
{
    // error: ‘void a’ has incomplete type
    // auto a = step(f);
    auto b = step(g, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like just cheating and forcing the function to always return a value:

```
template <class T> struct tag_type { using type = T; };
template <class T> constexpr tag_type<T> tag{};

namespace details {
    template <class F, class... Args>
    tag_type<void> call_impl(tag_type<void>, F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return {};
    }

    template <class R, class F, class... Args>
    R call_impl(tag_type<R>, F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}

template <class F, class... Args>
decltype(auto) call(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return details::call_impl(tag<std::result_of_t<F&&(Args&&...)>>,
       std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This way, `call(f, args...)` either gives you the return type correctly or an instance of `tag_type<void>`. That is, it always is an object.

This lets you rewrite your code as just:

```
template <typename TF>
auto step(TF&& f)
{   
    // Execute some actions before `f`. 
    do_something();

    decltype(auto) eventual_result = call(std::forward<TF>(f));

    // Execute some actions after `f`.
    do_something_after_f();

    return result;
}
```

regardless of its return type.

---

The above requires C++14, but is implementable in C++11 with an extra metafunction invocation to replace the `decltype(auto)` using in the main `call()` function template.